# change the call from a bash script in a month to a week

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 script in bash, and i have some files:

```
transaction-2012-01-01.csv.bz2
transaction-2012-01-02.csv.bz2
transaction-2012-01-03.csv.bz2
transaction-2012-01-04.csv.bz2
             .
             .
transaction-2012-01-31.csv.bz2
transaction-2012-02-01.csv.bz2
             .
             .
transaction-2012-02-28.csv.bz2
```

I have a script called script.sh

```
cat script.sh

YEAR_MONTH=$1
FILEPATH="transaction-$YEAR_MONTH*.csv.bz2"
bzcat $FILEPATH|strings|grep -v "code" >> output
```

And if you need call the script you can use other script

```
cat script2.sh

LAST_MONTH=$(date -d -1month +%Y"-"%m)
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  DATE=$1
else
  DATE=$LAST_MONTH  
fi

script.sh $DATE 1>output$DATE.csv 2>> log.txt
```

And it do cat the files in a month, but now i need call the script with a specific week in a year:

```
bash script2.sh 2012-01
```

where 2012 is the year and 01 is the month

Now i need call the script with:

```
bash script2.sh 2012 13
```

where 2012 is the year and 13 is the week in a year

Now i need the cat only to the files in the year and week that the user specified, no per month per week

But the format of the files do not help me!!!! because the name is transaction-year-month-day.csv.bz2, not transaction-year-week.csv.bz2

Comment: transaction-date.csv.bz2, where date can be 2012-01-02 or some date

Comment: So you are asking, "how in shell do I convert a year and a week number to its constituent year-month-day dates?"  Do weeks begin on Sunday or Monday?  Are weeks numbered 00 .. 53 or 01 .. 53 (ISO)?

Comment: Does your original script actually work?  There's a missing " ...

Comment: I update and it script works

Comment: Yes i need know the dates of the week for example the week 45 begin in 2013-11-04 and finish in 2013-11-10 i need the range of the dates

Comment: Your script contains several syntax errors (the `"` is still missing).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the manpage for [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). These are date format codes. For example:

```
$ date +"%A, %B %e, %Y at %I:%m:%S %p"
```

Will print out a date like:

```
Thursday, May 30, 2013 at 02:05:31 PM
```

Try to see why this works.

On ***some*** systems, the `date` command will have a `-j` switch. This means, don't set the date, but reformat the given date. This allows you to convert one date to another:

```
$ date -f"$input_format" "$string_date" +"$output_format"
```

The `$input_format` is the format of your input date. `$string_date` is the string representation of the date in your `$input_format`. And, `$output_format` is the format you want your date in.

The first two fields are easy. Your date is in `YY-MM-DD` format:

```
$ date -f"%Y-%m-%d" "$my_date_string"
```

The question is what can you do for the final format. Fortunately, there is a format for the week in the year. `%V` which represents the weeks at 01-53 and `%W` which represents the weeks as `00-53`.

What you need to do is find the date string on your file name, then convert that to the year and week number. If that's the same as the input, you need to concatenate this file.

```
find $dir -type f | while read transaction_file
do
    file_date=${transaction_file#transaction-}  #Removes the prefix
    file_date=${file_date%.csv.bz2}             #Removes the suffix
    weekdate=$(date -j -f"%Y-%m-%d" "$file_date" +"%Y %W")
    [ "$weekdate" -eq "$desired_date" ] || continue
    ...
done
```

For example, someone puts in `2013 05` as the desired date, you will go through all of your files and find ones with dates in the range you want. ***NOTE***: That the week of the year is zero filled. You may need to *zero fill* the input of the week number to match.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just enumerate the seven possible file names for a given week and pick the ones which exist, rather than run `find` on a potentially large directory just to pick out these seven files with (now) predictable names?

Comment: Okay, I want the 31st week in 2012. What are the seven possible dates? There's no easy way to do this using standard Unix utilities. Besides, if you have one file per day, you're talking about only 3652 files in 10 years. My laptop was able to process 71,000 in half a second using `find`. I'm not reading the files. I'm merely parsing directory information. The slow part will be uncompressing and concatenating out the files.

Comment: I had expected GNU `date` to be able to parse `date -d "week 31"` but alas, it doesn't.  I was able to establish that in 2012, week 31 started on day 211, but it wasn't as straightforward as I had envisioned it.  Unless you have a very large directory, looping over the files is the straightforward solution after all.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `coreutils` version of `date` does not have the `-j` option, and the `-f` option has entirely a different meaning.  `date -d "$file_date" +"%Y %W"` should work if you want to convert your script to use GNU `date`.

Comment: This ends up being a BSDism on date. I thought GNU/Linux had a similar mechanism. The OP hasn't commented on this one way or another. If this doesn't work, they'll have to switch over to a scripting language like Perl, Python, or Ruby.