# change the number of week by the range of dates in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i need change the number of week in a year by the range of dates, for example

i have the week number 46 in 2013

the range of dates is:

```
2013-11-11
2013-11-12
2013-11-13
2013-11-14
2013-11-15
2013-11-16
2013-11-17
```

I don't know can i do it with bash

The number is a parameter of the script for example if the script calls convertir.sh you use

```
convertir.sh 2013 46
```

where 2013 is a year and 46 is a week of the year
and the output of the script is the range of dates

Comment: Where is the week number? Give current output of your script and required output of your script.

Comment: What was the problem with the sensible answer in your other thread?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842168/change-the-call-from-a-bash-script-in-a-month-to-a-week

Comment: The number is a parameter of the script for example if the script calls convertir.sh you use convertir.sh 2013 46, and the output of the script is the range of dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work on linux with bash, assuming that by "week number", you mean the ISO week number. ISO weeks start on Monday and a week counts as part of a year if four of its days are in the year.

```
dates_for_week() {
  printf "January 1 $1 %+d days\n" {-3..368} |
    date +%G%V_%Y-%m-%d -f - |
    grep $(printf %d%02d $1 $2) |
    cut -c8-
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's a version which does less work to get the same result:

```
dates_for_week () { 
  printf "$1-01-01 +$2 weeks %+d days\n" {-10..2} |
    date +%V_%Y-%m-%d -f - |
    grep '^0\?'$2_ |
    cut -c4-
}
```

eg:

```
$ dates_for_week 2013 1
2012-12-31
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
2013-01-05
2013-01-06
$ dates_for_week 2013 46
2013-11-11
2013-11-12
2013-11-13
2013-11-14
2013-11-15
2013-11-16
2013-11-17
$ dates_for_week 2013 52
2013-12-23
2013-12-24
2013-12-25
2013-12-26
2013-12-27
2013-12-28
2013-12-29
```

Comment: @glennjackman: added a version which is better. Note that one way you could improve your answer is observing that January 4 is always in week 1 of the year, or in other words that mondayOfWeek1 is the last Monday no later than January 4, which I think is `date -d $(printf "$year-01-04 -%d days" $(date +%w -d $year-01-03))`

Comment: why that range of numbers?

Comment: @BenitoCamelas: January 4 must be in week 1, so week 1 must be included in [Jan 4 - 6 days, Jan 4 + 6 days]. Week `i` has the range `[Jan 4 + (i-1)*7 - 6 days, Jan 4 + (i-1)*7 + days]`. By simple arithmetic, that can be transformed to `[Jan 1 + i*7 - 10 days, Jan 1 + i*7 + 2 days]`, which is more convenient.

Comment: And why you do the grep with  grep '^0\?'$2_ ? , it is easier to use the command grep -i $2?, or i don't understand your grep... =(

Comment: And why you do the grep with  grep '^0\?'$2_ ? , it is easier to use the command grep -i $2_?, or i don't understand your grep... =(, and in date why -f- ?

Comment: i don´t understand the -f -, and in internet i did not find it

Comment: @BenitoCamelas: you should be able to get some information about the options for `date` by typing `man date` at a bash prompt. If you've got things installed right, you'll get more detailed information by typing `info date`. These tools should work for almost all command line utilities. `-f` means "read dates one line at a time from the file" and `-` as a filename means standard input. The grep option `-i` means "case-insensitive" and would have no effect here since the pattern consists only of digits. I anchor the pattern so that `1_` does not match `11_`.

Answer (score 0):

I love questions like this. Requires GNU date:

```
function mondayOfWeek1 {
    local year=$1 weeknum dayofweek adj=0
    # iso week num and day of week
    read weeknum dayofweek < <(date -d "$year-01-01" +"%V %w")
    # adjust based on wk num
    (( weeknum != 1 && $dayofweek >= 1)) && (( adj += 7 ))
    # adjust based on day of week
    (( adj += 1 - dayofweek ))
    date -d "$year-01-01 + $adj days" +"%Y-%m-%d"
}

function mondayOfWeek {
    local week=$1
    local year=${2-$(date +%Y)}
    date -d "$(mondayOfWeek1 $year) + $((week - 1)) weeks" +"%Y-%m-%d"
}


monday=$(mondayOfWeek 46)
for day in {0..6}; do 
    date -d "$monday + $day days" +"%Y-%m-%d"
done
```